# MongoDB hash object projection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, projection

If there is an object with unknown keys:

```
{
  data: {
    someObjectIdStringThatCantBePutInProjection: {
      dontReturn: 123,
      return: 321
    },
    someOtherObjectIdStringThatCantBePutInProjection: {
      dontReturn: 1234,
      return: 4321
    }
  }
}
```

And I want MongoDB to return only `return` property of the objects of the objects, what would the projection look like?

For example a projection

```
{
  data: { **allProperties**: { return: 1 } }
}
```

should return:

```
{
  data: {
    someObjectIdStringThatCantBePutInProjection: {
      return: 321
    },
    someOtherObjectIdStringThatCantBePutInProjection: {
      return: 4321
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic values as field names is considered an anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to queries. Nevertheless, you can convert the data object to an array of k-v tuples by `$objectToArray`. Use `$map` to get only the `return` field you need. Finally, use `$arrayToObject` to revert back to original form.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$data"
          },
          "as": "d",
          "in": {
            k: "$$d.k",
            v: {
              return: "$$d.v.return"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j8ltoFV7wve)